# Reading string from a text file and searching for it in another text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading from amex text file a list of strings and searching for each individual string in the failure text file and if I found the string I am searching for in the failure text file I am appending the string I am searching for in to a data_ticker list list. After that I am trying to write the list to another text file.

```
myfile = open("/home/mahmoud/Desktop/extract_failure.txt", "r").readlines()
ticker_list = open("/home/mahmoud/Desktop/amex.txt", "r").readlines()
data_ticker = []

for value in range(len(ticker_list)):
    if any(str(ticker_list[value]) in s for s in myfile):
       data_ticker.append(ticker_list[value])

with open('/home/mahmoud/Desktop/list.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in data_ticker:
       f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

The following is in the extract_failure text file:

```
ABBV: Unknown Symbol

ABEV: Unknown Symbol ABR^A: Unknown Symbol ABR^B: Unknown Symbol ABR^C: Unknown Symbol ACCO: Unknown Symbol ACRE: Unknown Symbol ADNT: Unknown Symbol ADSW: Unknown Symbol AFGE: Unknown Symbol AFGH: Unknown Symbol AGCO: Unknown Symbol AGM^A: Unknown Symbol AGM^B: Unknown Symbol AGM^C: Unknown Symbol AGO^B: Unknown Symbol AGO^E: Unknown Symbol AGO^F: Unknown Symbol AGRO: Unknown Symbol AHL^C: Unknown Symbol AHL^D: Unknown Symbol AHT^D: Unknown Symbol AHT^F: Unknown Symbol AHT^G: Unknown Symbol AHT^H: Unknown Symbol AHT^I: Unknown Symbol AI^B: Unknown Symbol AIG.WS: Unknown Symbol AIV^A: Unknown Symbol AIZP: Unknown Symbol AJRD: Unknown Symbol AJXA: Unknown Symbol ALEX: Unknown Symbol ALL^A: Unknown Symbol ALL^B: Unknown Symbol ALL^D: Unknown Symbol ALL^E: Unknown Symbol ALL^F: Unknown Symbol ALL^G: Unknown Symbol ALLE: Unknown Symbol ALLY: Unknown Symbol ALLY^A: Unknown Symbol ALP^Q: Unknown Symbol ALSN: Unknown Symbol AMBR: Unknown Symbol AMGP: Unknown Symbol AMH^D: Unknown Symbol AMH^E: Unknown Symbol AMH^F: Unknown Symbol AMH^G: Unknown Symbol AMH^H: Unknown Symbol AMID: Unknown Symbol AMOV: Unknown Symbol AMRC: Unknown Symbol AMRX: Unknown Symbol ANDX: Unknown Symbol ANET: Unknown Symbol ANFI: Unknown Symbol ANH^A: Unknown Symbol ANH^B: Unknown Symbol ANH^C: Unknown Symbol ANTM: Unknown Symbol APAM: Unknown Symbol APHA: Unknown Symbol APLE: Unknown Symbol APO^A: Unknown Symbol APO^B: Unknown Symbol APRN: Unknown Symbol APTS: Unknown Symbol APTV: Unknown Symbol AQNA: Unknown Symbol AQUA: Unknown Symbol ARCH: Unknown Symbol ARCO: Unknown Symbol ARDC: Unknown Symbol ARE^D: Unknown Symbol ARES: Unknown Symbol ARES^A: Unknown Symbol ARGD: Unknown Symbol
```

The following is in the amex text file:

```
A
AA
AAC
AAN
AAP
AAT
AB
ABB
ABBV
ABC
ABEV
ABG
ABM
ABR
ABR^A
ABR^B
ABR^C
ABT
AC
ACA
ACB
ACC
ACCO
ACH
ACM
ACN
ACP
ACRE
ACV
ADC
ADM
ADNT
ADS
ADSW
ADT
ADX
AEB
AED
```

The data can be copied into to text files and you can replicate the code. When I run the code the data_ticker list is empty, the code doesn't find matches of the string I am looking for in the failure text file

Comment: And what is the problem you are having? Make a usable example, I highly doubt anyone has a folder on their computer with the path `/home/mahmoud/Desktop/`

Comment: the problem is that when I read the data from the file and apply the search on it it doesn't find anything and the list stays empty

Comment: We cannot replicate that error if we do not have your file. Sorry.

Comment: So, your file is a bunch of uppercase letters separated by spaces?

Comment: @RafaelBarros I added in samples of the data so you can replicate the code.

Comment: And what is there in that `extract_failure.txt` file?

Comment: extract_failure is the failure text file I just made a mistake in the names. I edited the post

Comment: Hmm, `extract_failure.txt` does not seem to be parser friendly. First line is nice, a simple KEY: Value pair. Next one is empty, ok, easy to skip. And 3rd one contains a bunch of works with no clear delimiter. It would be much easier if every pair KEY: value could be on its own line!